# MSMQ Installed and still exception with queue

Tags: c#, msmq, queuing

I create private queues and already installed MSMQ and its corresponding service (Message Queueing) also started. But still I am getting this exception.

1. what be the issue here?
2. How to check whether message queueing service is avilable?

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: An error occurred
>   while receiving a message from the queue: The Message Queuing service
>   is not available (-1072824309, 0xc00e000b). Ensure that MSMQ is
>   installed and running. Make sure the queue is available to receive
>   from. ---> System.ServiceModel.MsmqException: An error occurred while
>   receiving a message from the queue: The Message Queuing service is not
>   available (-1072824309, 0xc00e000b). Ensure that MSMQ is installed and
>   running. Make sure the queue is available to receive from.
>                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqQueue.TryReceive(NativeMsmqMessage
>   message, TimeSpan timeout, MsmqTransactionMode transactionMode, Int32
>   action)
>                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqReceiveHelper.TryReceive(MsmqInputMessage
>   msmqMessage, TimeSpan timeout, MsmqTransactionMode transactionMode,
>   MsmqMessageProperty& property)
>                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqInputChannelBase.TryReceive(TimeSpan
>   timeout, Message& message)
>                  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqInputChannelBase.TryReceive(TimeSpan
>   timeout, Message& message)
>                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputChannel.HelpReceive(IInputChannel
>   channel, TimeSpan timeout)
>                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqInputChannelBase.Receive(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>                  at TyMetrix.Enterprise.Channels.ChunkingChannel.ChunkingChannel.Receive(TimeSpan
>   timeout) in c:\app\dev\Proc\ChunkingChannel\ChunkingChannel.cs:line
>   194
>                  at TyMetrix.Enterprise.Channels.ChunkingChannel.ChunkingChannel.TryReceive(TimeSpan
>   timeout, Message& message) in
>   c:\app\dev\Proc\ChunkingChannel\ChunkingChannel.cs:line 232
>                  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InputChannelBinder.TryReceive(TimeSpan
>   timeout, RequestContext& requestContext)
>                  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.TryReceive(TimeSpan
>   timeout, RequestContext& requestContext)

Comment: Code would be useful. But the exception says the MSMQ service isn't running.

Comment: @JackHughes MSMQ service name is Message Queuing right? It is still running. I checked in services.msc

Comment: Google the error code, debug your MSMQ installation....

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni, I already did and could not found any possible solution for my case, so checking here

Comment: Code you are using would be helpful.

Comment: If you are sure that the service is running then it must be "Make sure the queue is available to receive from". Have you created the queue?

Comment: @JackHughes, Yes the queues are created. Queue is available to receive from?

Comment: The service is running, and the queue exists, I bet it is permissions. Does your code have permission to read from the queue. Change permission so anybody can read/write and see if it works?

Comment: @JackHughes Yes, I have given permission for EveryOne to full control for the queues

Comment: Must be your code then... which you still haven't posted.